# SQL PHP Dividing columns dual queries

Tags: php, sql, divide

Below is the code in question. I'm trying to get a simple division from two columns, but in an already existing (and functioning) php query set up. I can not seem to get it to work no matter what I do. I am not a strong coder by any means. The code outputs a capital S.

```
<?php
include("db_reader.php");

$data = '';

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE team like 'Replay%'";
if (!$result = mysql_query($query)) {
    exit(mysql_error());
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $number = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $kdresult = "SELECT (kills / deaths) AS kdresult FROM users WHERE team like 'Replay%'";
        $data .= '
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <div id="memberCard-1" class="card">
        <div class="face front">
            <div class="panel panel-default text-center" style="border: 1px solid red;">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#000;color:#ff0000;">
                <h3 class="panel-title">'.$row['name'].'</h3>
                </div>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">Position</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Info</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"></li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Kills: '.$row['kills'].'</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Deaths: '.$row['deaths'].'</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">KD: '.$kdresult['kdresult'].'</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your $kdresult is a query but it's not being run anywhere.

Could you change your $query to be:

```
$query = "SELECT kills, deaths, kills/deaths AS kdresult FROM users WHERE team like 'Replay%'";
```

It's better practice to specify the columns you actually need in a SELECT statement rather than SELECT *. This also means your data is in a single query and not in two queries.

Comment: So you gave me insight and combined with more fast past general php/sql learning what ended up fixing it was changing the first pquery to below. I needed to call * because I am using all the columns in that table for out put. What I didn't realize is that the &kdresult wasn't being run, so I added the division into the first query. 

     $pquery = "SELECT *, kills/deaths AS kdresult FROM users WHERE team LIKE '%".$teamname."%' ORDER by capt DESC, name ASC";